# C recovering image from SD logic

Tags: c

I'm trying to recover data from an SD card FAT32 knowing that when I find a `.jpg` there, it will be there in order till the end of file.
Right now the program is able to recover 1 jpeg but stops.  How can I improve it, or can someone point me the logic flaw?

Also at: http://pastebin.com/Rak6L5Z0

EDIT: card file  http://www.mediafire.com/?et8pvhvacpy9kv1

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdint.h>

 typedef uint8_t BYTE;

 #define BLOCKSIZE 512

 int main(void)
 {
    // define 512 byte block
    BYTE block[BLOCKSIZE];

    // open memory card
    FILE* fp = fopen("card.raw", "r");

    // check if file opened
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // open output file
    FILE* outfile;
    outfile = NULL;
    int num = 0;
    char filename[14];
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;

    // main block till end of file
    while (y == 1)
    {
        if ( x == 0)
        {
        // read every 512 block
        fread(&block, sizeof(block), 1 , fp);
        }

        // if 4 first characters jpg
        if ((block[0] == 0xff && block[1] == 0xd8 && block[2] == 0xff && block[3] == 0xe0) || (block[0] == 0xff && block[1] == 0xd8 && block[2] == 0xff && block[3] == 0xe1))
        {
            sprintf(filename, "%03d_output.jpg", num);
            outfile = fopen(filename, "a");
            fwrite(&block, sizeof(block), 1, outfile);
            //fseek(fp, sizeof(block), SEEK_CUR);

            fread(&block, sizeof(block), 1 , fp);
            while (!((block[0] == 0xff && block[1] == 0xd8 && block[2] == 0xff && block[3] == 0xe0) || (block[0] == 0xff && block[1] == 0xd8 && block[2] == 0xff && block[3] == 0xe1)))
            {
                fwrite(&block, sizeof(block), 1, outfile);
                y = fread(&block, sizeof(block), 1, fp);
            }
            //fseek(fp, -(sizeof(block)), SEEK_CUR);
            fclose(outfile);
            num++;
            x = 1;
            //y = fread(&block, sizeof(block), 1, fp);
        }
        //printf("%s\n", block);

    }

    // close memory card
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: FAT32 doesn't necessarily store all blocks of a file in a contiguous block. Your program would need to read and follow the file allocation table (FAT) to find the blocks for each file you wish to recover. Start by looking for a FAT32 specification document. Or maybe just look for a pre-existing recovery application rather than writing your own.

Comment: it's an exercise where i know some stuff like that every 512bytes If I find a .jpg then there are .jpg till the end of file. it's a thing for beginners but I don't understand while after the first .jpg it doesn't print the others.  (I know that there are 51 .jpg to recover), with an infinite while loop before I was able to find all 51 but without making them correctly in the output file, now I can output 1 correctly but nothing else happens, any idea on that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is the outer loop:

```
while (y == 512)
{
    ...lots of code...
    y = fread(&block, sizeof(block), 1, fp);
    ...some code...
}
```

The `fread()` sets `y` to `0` or `1`, so it is no longer 512, so the loop terminates.

I think there is also a problem with the `if (x == 0)` followed by `x = 1;`, but I'm not sure I understand the logic behind that part of the code.  Certainly, `x` is not reset to zero after the first file is read — if that matters.

---

This extracts files 000..050 from the sample data, and `file` describes them all as one of these three types:

- JPEG image data, EXIF standard
- JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
- JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02

#### Working code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

#define BLOCKSIZE 512

static inline int is_jpeg_file_header(const BYTE *block)
{
    if (block[0] == 0xff && block[1] == 0xd8 && block[2] == 0xff &&
            (block[3] == 0xe0 || block[3] == 0xe1))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    BYTE block[BLOCKSIZE];
    const char file[] = "card.raw";

    FILE* fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s for reading\n", file);
        return 1;
    }

    int num = 0;

    while (fread(&block, sizeof(block), 1, fp) == 1)
    {
        if (is_jpeg_file_header(block))
        {
            char filename[20];
            snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%03d_output.jpg", num);
            FILE* outfile = fopen(filename, "a");
            if (outfile == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s for writing\n", filename);
                return 1;
            }
            printf("%s\n", filename);

            fwrite(&block, sizeof(block), 1, outfile);
            while (fread(&block, sizeof(block), 1 , fp) == 1 &&
                    !is_jpeg_file_header(block))
            {
                fwrite(&block, sizeof(block), 1, outfile);
            }
            fclose(outfile);
            num++;
            fseek(fp, -BLOCKSIZE, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

This uses the fact that we're reading a disk image to seek back one block when you read the header of the next file.  It is simpler than continuing the code.

The first 11 recovered images are all displayable in a web browser.

Comment: I read somewhere that fread(..) returns the value of bytes read, in this case 512 that's why I did put (y == 512).  I tried to modify it to while (y == 1) ... but with that it creates a 000.jpg file correctly and then a 001.jpg 1gb+ file and never stops looping.

about the  x yeah it's on purpose

Comment: The declaration of the function is: `size_t fread(void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems, FILE *restrict stream);`. The first size argument is the size of the units it is counting; the second is the number of units it is counting. It will return the number of units it read successfully. If you have `1` as the first size argument, then it does indeed report the number of bytes read. If (as in your code) you have `sizeof(block)` for the first size, and 1 for the second size, then `fread()` will return either 0 (didn't read as much as one block) or 1 (it did read a block).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
I updated the code and added a link for the 3.4mb sd card file, now I get an infinite loop in the program, don't understand why

Comment: thanks a lot, now I see the logic that I should have used and understand why I was getting the "infinite loop", if you don't mind I would like to understand 2 more things about your code: 1) I know that this is a small program so doesn't matter but would be ok to leave   char filename[20]   inside the loop or for better practice declare it outside of the loop ?   
2) about fseek, nvm now I understand why fseek =p

Comment: Regarding (1), I generally keep variables limited to the minimum scope that's feasible.  There'd be no harm in defining `filename` outside the loop beyond the fact that it is only needed inside the loop.  Regarding (2), there could be circumstances under which the `fseek()` is undesirable — if the input was coming from a terminal or a pipe, for example.  In that case, there'd need to be some more contorted logic, more like the original code, to ensure that each block was written once.  But since the information was coming from file, it simplifies life enormously to use the `fseek()`.